# Thermal Conductance of a Pyroelectric sensor

Tags: sensor, thermal

For some temperature changes, I want to use a pyroelectric sensor. I have been looking for the R.G. Whatmore's papers for the basic theory. In the paper, for calculating the time constant. He mentioned that it is *t* = H/G. Where H is the heat capacity and G is the thermal conductance. However, I cannot find any detailed information about this calculation. My question is how this thermal conductance, G, is calculated?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper(s)? Which, if any, of [**these**](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/r.whatmore/publications.html)  are relevant ?